# DotNetNuke "keepalive"

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

I've got a couple DNN portals I manage and I need a solution to keep them "alive" during slack traffic times.  After a given time of inactivity IIS will unload the DNN application from memory which will effect load time for the first client request.  DNN has the "KeepAlive.aspx" file that I hit with a wget command from a CRON job every 5 minutes.  I'm dubious of the effectiveness of the this method.  Does anyone have any others ideas?

Comment: Why are you dubious about the effectiveness of the method? You keep the app alive in IIS by starting or keeping a session active within the appropriate window and the method described should do exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good website monitoring service will most likely provide you with a URL to check to see if the site is functioning, that is what the Keepalive URL is for. Have the service check the URL more frequently than 15 minutes and you should be good to go with keeping the site up. There's always a chance the site will go down for some other issue, but the keep alive service should bring it back up if that happens and another user hasn't already hit it.

Answer (score 1):

In the Global application start event, you could set up a cache item or timer with a timeout of 5 minutes, and in the callback code, ping a simple page that should return HTTP 200 - reset the cache/timer, and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a service there are a number of them out there, some free some not

- [Host-Tracker](http://www.host-tracker.com)
- [Pingdom](http://www.pingdom.com)
- KeepAliveForever

I have used both Host-Tracker and Pingdom before, they are great as they notify you of outages as well